# hex to binary to string

Tags: java, string, append

I need to take the hex numbers from this byte array and convert them into binary and then put all of the binary into a single string. A

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String binary;
    byte [] ex;
    ex = new byte [] {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0x11, (byte)0xEE, (byte)0x22, (byte)0xDD, (byte)0x33, (byte)0xCC, (byte)0x44};
    printByteArray(ex);
    binary = hexToBin(ex);
    System.out.println(binary);
}

public static String hexToBin(byte [] array)
{
    String binStr = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        binStr.append(Integer.toBinaryString(array[i]));
    }
    return binStr;
}
```

but due to the fact of how I initialized the string (my first attempt) my output had 'null' in it. Any ideas how to fix that? Also I just changed it to append  as to fix the problem I had with null and now I don't know why but it won't let me use it.

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT **

okay that worked so now i have:

```
    public static void main (String[] args){

    String binary;
    String binary2;
    byte [] ex;
    byte [] wx;
    ex = new byte [] {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0x11, (byte)0xEE, (byte)0x22, (byte)0xDD, (byte)0x33, (byte)0xCC, (byte)0x44};
    wx = new byte [] {(byte)0x12, (byte)0xCD, (byte)0xD8, (byte)0x53, (byte)0xFA, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x1C, (byte)0x40};
    printByteArray(ex);
    binary = hexToBin(ex);
    System.out.println(binary);
    binary2 = hexToBin(wx);
    System.out.println(binary2);

}

public static String hexToBin(byte [] array)
{
    StringBuilder binStr = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        binStr.append(Integer.toBinaryString(array[i]));
    }
    return binStr.toString();
}
```

but this is my output:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111100011111111111111111111111111110111010001011111111111111111111111111011101110011111111111111111111111111110011001000100
1001011111111111111111111111111001101111111111111111111111111110110001010011111111111111111111111111111110101111001000000
```

any idea why they are diff lengths? and how can i make them so they are the same length. like on the first one FF should be '11111111' but if i put spaces in between the separate bytes in the array when converting them, FF come out to be like '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111' and i only want the 8 bit representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just replace the `binStr` `String` type with a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static String hexToBin(byte[] array) {
   StringBuilder binStr = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      binStr.append(Integer.toBinaryString(array[i]));
   }

   return binStr.toString();
}
```

**Update:**

As `toBinaryString` doesn't left-pad with zeros you may want to use (8-bit LHS padded):

```
String binaryString = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(array[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
binStr.append(binaryString);
```

Comment: do i have to change public static _String_ as well to StringBuilder? and the would append work?

Comment: No, you can return the result of [StringBuilder#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString()) which is a `String`

Comment: Won't work because toBinaryString doesn't left pad with zeroes

Comment: okay awesome! Got it. one more quick question though. Just see the edit on my op.

Comment: Sorry just trying to learn. the second output though is still short 16 numbers though, which is what im trying to fix because i need to compare the two

Comment: thanks for your help @Reimeus but like i said earlier is there any way to just have 8 binary bits per hex number?

Comment: thank you. you are a god. lol. I already tried the %8s with no luck, seeing as how i left the 0xFF out. Thanks for your patience